# C# Class methods can't see objects created in same class's Main()

Tags: c#

This is probably something really basic, but I'm not sure what's wrong:

```
partial class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        ADAttributes allObjectAttributes = new ADAttributes("AllObjects");

    }

    static void calcs() {

        var x = allObjectAttributes; // <--- Name does not exist in the current context

    }

}
```

Why is the `calcs()` method unable to see `allObjectAttributes` that was created in `Main()`?

Comment: Because your `allObjectAttributes` is a local variable, not a a class member (could only be a static class member anyway, since `Main` is static)

Comment: Variables are bound to the scope they're _declared_ in, so `allObjectAttributes` is local to the `Main` method body. Move the `ADAttributes allObjectAttributes` declaration out to the `Program` class and mark it static in order to access it from `calcs()`

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Scope of Variables in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/)**  also **[Basic Concepts - Declarations in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#73-declarations)**

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, and PMF.  Brilliant.  I had actually already tried that and it still didn't work.  I just didn't declare it static.  It's fine now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because C# does not work that way. The scope of the variable `allObjectAttribute` is to the Main-method, only in that method is the variable visible/usable.

If you want to have access to the variable from another method, you have to create a class field, and in your case, a static one.

Comment: Or a static property.